# How do I run an API endpoint deployed to Vercel? (not using Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, vercel

I've got a bit of a weird set up here with a codebase that I inherited. It's a CRA app deployed to Vercel but *doesn't* use Next.js.

**Problem: I'm not able to call `myapp.com/nonce` from Postman or access it in my browser to see the JSON response.** There's some configuration stuff that's not quite right, just trying to figure out what that is. Would love any help here!

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
Project (create-react-app)
   src
     bunch of React code
   server
     index.js
     package.json
   package.json
```

(It's not using next.js. If it were, I'd just use the `/pages/api/*` files)

In my top-level `package.json`, I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && cd server && npm install && npm run start",
}
```

and in my `/server/package.json` I have just a simple `start` command: `node index.js`

My `server/index.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../MyProject/build')));


app.get('/nonce', async (req, res) => {
  const { address } = req.query;
  const quantity = snapshot[address];

  return res.json({ quantity, address }); // for testing 
})
```

Edit:

With this as-is, my `build` phase never actually completes.. It runs a server at 3001 and that's the last log of the Build log

```
> MyProject-server@0.1.0 start /vercel/path0/server
> node index.js
Server listening on 3001
```

Comment: Please mention full url that you are trying to call API from postman